# Using custom validator to compare two form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, form-fields

I'm working on learning custom validations in rails and am attempting to apply it for the purpose of comparing two form fields.  So far, I can easily pass one value to the custom my custom validator which I've stored in `app/validation/pin_validator.rb` and it works fine.  But I'd *really* like to set up something like the following that would accept two pieces of data from the form:

```
class PinValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each (record, attribute, value)
    if value1 > value2
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "validator working")
    end
  end
end
```

And call it from the model with something like this:

```
validates :pin_number, :id_string, pin: true
```

Where `:id_string` and `:pin_number` are both form fields and would be compared as `value1` and `value2`

Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

**Note:** The value comparison above really could be solved on the front-end with a little javascript.  The reason I'm asking for a serverside solution is that I ultimately intend to compare both values with a set of entries in the database.  The example above is just to distil my question to something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access attributes listed with `@attributes` inside the `validate_each` method, as you can infer from the initializer code [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a7da19acadf32fcaaddf707ac79d1fefb6a9c50d/activemodel/lib/active_model/validator.rb#L150-L158)

So you can access `record` attributes by using values from `@attributes` which is an array with the attribute names used on the definition of the validation, in your case `[:pin_number, :id_string]`. You can access them like

```
def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
   value1 = record[@attributes[0]] # :pin_number
   value2 = record[@attributes[1]] # :id_string
   # the rest of the logic here
end
```

I realize the `validate_each` method is going to be run twice as it is supposed to run for each of the fields listed on the validation definition. That might lead to errors being inserted twice or other issues. I am researching if the validator instance is created every time a validation is to be run, if so you could avoid this double validation by setting up a flag, say `@already_run` and then just returning if that flag was true the second time. As a new instance of the validator would be created next time anything needed to be validated then the flag wouldn't affect anything else.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response!  I'm afraid I don't follow (I'm rather new to rails) could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sure, adding to the response now, but basically, you can check the `@attributes` instance variable, which is an array of symbols, where each symbol is the name of each of the attributes listed on the validation declaration as `validates :attrib1, :attrib2, pin: true`

Comment: YOU, sir, are a rockstar; many thanks!  An odd quirk that I didn't quite expect is that in order to get both `value1` and `value2` working, I needed to include both `:pin_number`, and `:id_string` in my validation call, like so `validates :pin_number, :id_string, pin: true`

Comment: Wasn't that the intended interface?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't what the intended interface?

Comment: Didn't you want to setup the validations as `validates :pin_number, :id_string, pin: true`? I don't understand what you mean by "odd quirk"

Comment: Oh, yes.  I had briefly (foolishly) thought that the method that you gave worked independently of the parameters I sent.  Just my noob sense of how rails works (it's getting better but still shaky).  I just decided to include that detail in my comment in case anyone else who runs across the answer was under the same misconception as I was.  Anyway, nothing for you to worry about; your answer was perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing the validation on the Rails side you might consider doing the JS approach of validation the values `onClick` or on some other action that you feel give you the proper control.

All you would need for `onClick` is a simple method to grab the values from each uniquely named form field and then just compare the `val()`s of each field and allow/deny submission.

In the case that you need to compare the form fields to a value stored in the DB you can use `<input type="hidden>` and store that value when the page is loaded so that comparison can still be done in the same manner described above.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the advice.  Given the application above, you're quite right; that would be the best way to do it.  However, I'm really just using the value comparison above to distil the concept I'm trying to learn.  Ultimately I want to pass two values in to be compared with a set of database values, which is why I'm interested in the rails side.

Comment: I actually don't know if what you are trying is possible with a rails custom validation. I'm curious if someone has a nice trick to handle this.

Comment: You can still solve this with JS though by storing the value in a hidden field or something like that and comparing when ready. I'll update my answer to include that since I think that might be the best approach.

Comment: Fair point, my only issue is that the table I'm querying has hundreds of thousands of values in it which seems rather heavy to load on the front end.  Granted, my application is a little odd.  Thanks for your thoughts though.

Comment: seems like a candidate for an index on that column and that `pin` that you are trying to use. I'd do some benchmarking but I don't think this should be too costly even with 1000s of values. GL.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I'll have a look into that then.  Certainly seems to be the best option so far :-)

Comment: Remember that form submissions from the Scary Internet do not need to comply with any Javascript validations.  A malicious user can submit anything they want, no restrictions on the parameters or their contents.  Unless you trust every user, the Rails app should be prepared to handle arbitrary or malicious form submissions.

Comment: mwfearnley's point * 1000. Massively important to sanitize your data. Rails has some nice helpers to keep you safe